# Exception in Deserialize process

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

I wrote a dll which has several classes. One of them is  called DataDesign.

```
[Serilizible]
public class DataDesign
    {
        [NonSerialized]
        HorizantalFields _horizantalFields;
        [NonSerialized]
        VerticalFields _verticalFields;
        [NonSerialized]
        GeneralDataDesignViewType _dataDesignView;
        [NonSerialized]
        Dictionary<FieldTemplateType, string> _templateTable;
        [NonSerialized]
        public List<string> ProcessedData;

        List<IField> _fields; 
    }
```

When I use this dll in my application I have a problem in deserilizing process. Serilizing ends up with successesful. But in deserialization I have an EXCEPTION.

The Exception is

> "Unable to find assembly 'AnalyzingData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

AnalyzingData is name of dll.

```
DeSerilizeClass()
{
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    dataDesign=new DataDesign();

                    DataDesign dd= (DataDesign)bin.Deserialize(stream);
}

Serilize()
{
                    using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Parameters.SavedConfigurationsDirectory, dataDesignName),FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                        bin.Serialize(sr, this);
                    }
}
```

//this datadesign class

How I can  solve this problem?

MS visual Studio2010 . Windows 7
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear enough?

Comment: `Version=1.0.0.0` is the usual hangup.  What is the [AssemblyVersion] of your current AnalyzingData.dll?  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever process is deserializing needs to have access to your AnalyzingData Dll, i.e. it needs to be in the bin folder of that app or other place that it can load it from.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

`BinaryFormatter` serializes the *concrete* objects in a graph. Even if you expose something as `IField`, `BinaryFormatter` is only looking at the actual `SomeTypeOfField : IField` instances. This means that to deserialize this data you need the assemblies that were in use when you serialized the data. It sounds like when you serialized, it was getting some types (in the graph) from the `AnalyzingData` assembly. This means that to *deserialize* this data, you are going to need this assembly again.

There are some complicated ways of working around this with `Binder`, but in most cases I would advise choosing a serializer that maps to your scenario: if you want to deserialize without the same original types / assemblies, then you should use a contract-based serializer.

Alternatively, just find `AnalyzingData.dll`, and add a reference to it so that it gets deployed with your application (set the copy-local to true, too).

Comment: Exactly what I must do eliminate this exception?